# How to follow HTTPResponse in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I get this error below when I GET my google apps script.

```
ERROR: The script completed but did not return anything.
```

Since I will be posting to my app (which redirects to my app when the post is complete), I should be automatically redirected back to my app?

```
function doGet(e){
  var options = {
    "method" : 'POST',
    "payload" : "user_id="+e.parameter.user_id+"&gmail="+getEmail()
  };
  var url = 'http://somedomain.com/users/give_gmail_permission/';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  return response;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I follow HTTPResponse in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1):

change the line:

```
return response
```

for

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b>"+response.getResponseCode()+"</b><br>"+response.getContentText()).
  setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
```

the modified script:

```
function doGet(e){
  var options = {
    "method" : 'POST',
    "payload" : "user_id="+e.parameter.user_id+"&gmail="+getEmail()
  };
  var url = 'http://somedomain.com/users/give_gmail_permission/';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log("response code: "+response.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log("response: "+response.getContentText());
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b>"+response.getResponseCode()+"</b><br>"+response.getContentText()).
  setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```